# Find the basis.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Given,$W=\{(u,v,w,x): u+w+x=0,u+w-2x=0,v=x\}$ subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$

The problem is this,  $u+w+x=0,u+w-2x=0$

I can get only one member $(-1,0,1,0)$ of basis elements.

I don't understand is there more members or not?

If not then why?

How could one deal with these types equations?

Comment: @Dietrich Burde  No, $(0,0,0,0)$ can't be member of basis.

Comment: Aah, a *basis*, that's different. Of course we have $x=0$ by substracting the first two equations. So $v=0$ as well and $u+w=0$. Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $v=x$, $u+w+x=0$ and $u+w-2x=0$. That is $u+w=-x$ and $u+w=2x$, i.e., $-x=2x$ and so $x=0$.

Then $v=0$ and $u+w=0$, i.e., $u=-w$.

Indeed, the basis consists of the vector $(-1, 0, 1, 0)$. All elements of the subspace are scalar multiple of this vector.